# Ruby: Instantiating a new variable within a block

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to shorten my Ruby code.

```
def count_palindromes_in_an(array)
  palindromes = 0
  array.each { |word| palindromes += 1 if word == word.reverse }
  return palindromes
end
```

so that palindromes is instantiated within the block executed by the each method. Something along the lines of;

```
def count_palindromes_in_an(array)
  array.each { |word| (palindromes != nil ? palindromes += 1 : palindromes = 1) if word == word.reverse }
  return palindromes
end
```

However this returns an error of `undefined method 'palindromes'`. Any tips gratefully received.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not going to work because a block creates a new scope. Variables defined inside the block are isolated from the outer scope.

```
[1].each do
  palindromes = 1
  local_variables #=> [:palindromes]
end

local_variables #=> []
```

To count array elements, use [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
array.count { |word| word == word.reverse }
```

You could even add a `palindrome?` method to `String`:

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    self == reverse
  end
end
```

And shorten your code to:

```
array.count(&:palindrome?)
```

Comment: Great answear but I do not think monkey patching is a good idea.

Comment: Good explanation, Stefan! But I feel that my answer helps the OP better achieve what he wanted.

Comment: @Humza I'd say no. `count` is more idiomatic and makes code even shorter. Yet yes, the last solution with monkey-patching core classes doesn't look great, but let's assume the OP will read this and be warned.

Comment: Stefan, You're right! - I had overlooked something earlier. Upvoted your answer.